# How to get IcePush to work with Vaadin?

Tags: java, widget, vaadin, icepush

I am getting `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` while trying to get IcePush client up and running. `GWTPushContext.getInstance()` throws the error when it is at the initialization method of the IcePush listener.

The method should be called in correct context I suppose. What all files / packages need to be present so that I am able to make this call?

I have widget-set initialization xml and the service is mentioned in `web.xml`.

Comment: I was following tutorial on http://wiki.icefaces.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1278114&navigatingVersions=true so that I was trying to add the given code to empty project. Tutorial itself was made for modifying existing GWT example code, so no wonder the code did not work alone. I'll post this as answer whenever I follow the tutorial line by line..and I get it working!

Comment: My work mate got icepush up and running with servlets but there is still much until it works as portlet. [This tutorial may help](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/233732) - the last post there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Vaadin and IcePush to work in Liferay/Glassfish environment with Eclipse tool, you need at least the following:
a) Eclipse needs Vaadin toolkit
b) [Follow this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/233732), the last post from Mark
c) The demo project there has some imports wrong and some depregated code. Those can be fixed with Eclipse suggestions and some use of Google. Also you need to add portal-service-6.0.2.jar and portlet-api-2.0.jar to get the imports ok.
d) For Vaadin you need also vaadin-6.5.6.jar
There may be some other corrections needed to the project setup, but those can be asked via comments to this post. I follow this forum daily and am pleased to answer questions.

Comment: Best practice on Vaadin is to believe the Eclipse plugin, not any of the documentation online. They're developing Vaadin so fast that the plugin is the only place that keeps in the pace.